# Identifying which core-transition has completed in core-transitionend

Tags: javascript, polymer

Here is a page that displays a div and moves it on and off screen using core-transition-css elements. It also captures the core-transitionend event, which  fires at the end of any core-transition animation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-transition/core-transition-css.html" />
    <title>Core Transition CSS Event</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <polymer-element name="test-app" on-core-transitionend="{{animationCompleted}}">
        <script>
            Polymer({
                state : {"opened": false},
                transition : null,
                ready : function() {
                    var target = this.$.myDiv;
                    this.transition = this.$.centerAnimation;

                    target.removeAttribute('hidden');
                    this.transition.setup(target, this.state);
                    this.async(this.centerButtonClick, null, 100);
                },
                centerButtonClick : function() {
                    var target = this.$.myDiv;
                    if(this.transition){
                        this.transition.teardown(target);
                    }
                    this.state.opened = !this.state.opened;
                    this.transition = this.$.centerAnimation; 
                    this.transition.setup(target);
                    this.transition.go(target, this.state);
                },
                rightButtonClick : function() {
                    var target = this.$.myDiv;
                    if(this.transition){
                        this.transition.teardown(target);
                    }
                    this.state.opened = !this.state.opened;
                    this.transition = this.$.rightAnimation; 
                    this.transition.setup(target);
                    this.transition.go(target, this.state);
                },
                animationCompleted : function(e) {
                    alert('animation complete')
                }
            });
        </script>
        <template>
            <style>
                #myDiv {
                  color: white;
                  background-color: blue;
                  position: fixed;
                  top: 100px;
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 400px;
                }
            </style>
            <paper-button on-click="{{centerButtonClick}}">Center</paper-button>
            <paper-button on-click="{{rightButtonClick}}">Right</paper-button>
            <paper-button>None</paper-button>
            <div id="myDiv" hidden>It's a div</div>
            <core-transition-css id="centerAnimation" transitionType="center"></core-transition-css>
            <core-transition-css id="rightAnimation" transitionType="right"></core-transition-css>
        </template>
    </polymer-element>
    <test-app id="myTest"></test-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to be able to tell which animation is complete from inside the event handler. If you click one of the first two buttons on the page you'll see that there are actually two alerts: one for the animation of the div and one for the end of the ripple animation on paper-button (the None button is there to show that you get an alert for any paper-button click, even those that don't cause an animation of the div to occur).

I may be missing something, but I was hoping the event object passed to animationCompleted(e) would have the core-transition-css element as its srcElement. Unfortunately, both the srcElement and target are set to test-app#myTest.

Additionally, the documentation for core-transition says that e.detail should contain the target node, however e.detail seems to always be set to null in core-transition.html:

```
 /**
   * Called when the animation completes. This function also fires the
   * `core-transitionend` event.
   *
   * @method complete
   * @param {Node} node The animated node
   */
  complete: function(node) {
    this.fire('core-transitionend', null, node);
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I poked with it for the last 30min.. I think the only work around is to create a quick custom element, e.g.:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-core-transition-css" extends="core-transition-css" attributes="transitionType">
    <template>
      <link no-shim rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/core-transition/core-transition-overlay.css">
    </template>
    <script>
     Polymer('custom-core-transition-css', {

        complete: function(node) {
            this.fire("core-transitionend", {
                id: this.getAttribute("id"),
                transition: this.transitionStyle,
            }, node);
        }

    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And then just change the  core-transition-css to custom-core-transition-css:

```
<custom-core-transition-css id="centerAnimation" transitionType="center"></custom-core-transition-css>
<custom-core-transition-css id="rightAnimation" transitionType="right"></custom-core-transition-css>
```

You can keep all your existing code and just get the transitionStyle and Id via the `e.detail`:

```
animationCompleted : function(e) {
    console.log(e.detail);
}
```

Which returns:

```
Object {id: "centerAnimation", transition: style}
Object {id: "rightAnimation", transition: style}
Object {}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Now, we could propose to the Polymer group to just change the core-transition component and directly integrate that information.

Comment: I created a pull request in core-transition to have this added.